# Capture outer paren/bracket groups while ignoring inner paren groups

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

This is a permutation of my [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024714/capture-outer-paren-groups-while-ignoring-inner-paren-groups). The answer worked perfectly for me until I ran into an edge case that caused a problem. I now need a tweaked regex pattern. I have tried to work it out on my own at [Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester), but my knowledge of regex isn't quite advanced enough for this.

The one change from my previous post (linked above) is that I am now only interested in matching paren groupings that begin with `([` instead of merely `(`. The end of the grouping remains the same: `)`

For the sake of completeness, here is the entire previous question, modified for the new requirement:

I'm using C# and regex, trying capture outer paren groups while ignoring inner paren groups. I have legacy-generated text files containing thousands of string constructions like the following:

```
([txtData] of COMPOSITE
(dirty FALSE)
(composite [txtModel])
(view [star3])
(creationIndex 0)
(creationProps )
(instanceNameSpecified FALSE)
(containsObject nil)
(sName txtData)
(txtDynamic FALSE)
(txtSubComposites )
(txtSubObjects )
(txtSubConnections )
)

([txtUI] of COMPOSITE
(dirty FALSE)
(composite [txtModel])
(view [star2])
(creationIndex 0)
(creationProps )
(instanceNameSpecified FALSE)
(containsObject nil)
(sName ApplicationWindow)
(txtDynamic FALSE)
(txtSubComposites )
(txtSubObjects )
(txtSubConnections )
)

([star38] of COMPOSITE
(dirty FALSE)
(composite [txtUI])
(view [star39])
(creationIndex 26)
(creationProps composite [txtUI] sName Bestellblatt)
(instanceNameSpecified TRUE)
(containsObject COMPOSITE)
(sName Bestellblatt)
(txtDynamic FALSE)
(txtSubComposites )
(txtSubObjects )
(txtSubConnections )
)
```

I am looking for a regex that will capture the 3 groupings in the example above, and here is the solution from the previous SO post:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\)(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\)"); 
return regex.Matches(str);
```

I need a slight tweak to the regex pattern above so that it only matches groupings that begin with `([` and not merely with `(`. The end remains the same: `)`

The requirement match is simple:

1. Opening paren + square bracket (`([`) is either the first character in the file, or it follows a `newline`.
2. Closing paren is either the last character in the file, or it is followed by a `newline`.

I want the regex pattern to ignore all paren-groupings that don't obey numbers 1 and 2 above. By "ignore" I mean that they shouldn't be seen as a match - but they should be returned as part of the outer grouping match.

So, for my objective to be met, when my C# regex runs against the example above, I should get back a regex `MatchCollection` with exactly 3 matches, just as shown above.

How is it done?

Comment: `Regex.Matches(text, @"(?=\(\[)^\((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\)(?<-c>))*\)\r?$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may apply a positive lookahead at the start of the pattern that would require the `[` after the initial `(`. Also, since the leading `([` can only appear at the start of a line and closing `)` can only appear at the end of a line, it makes sense to add `^` and `\r?$` anchors (note `\r?` is necessary as `$` in the multiline mode only matches a location before `\n`, not before `\r`).

So, your regex may be adjusted to

```
var results = Regex.Matches(text, 
                  @"^\((?=\[)(?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\)(?<-c>))*\)\r?$", 
                  RegexOptions.Multiline)
              .Cast<Match>()
              .Select(x => x.Value)
              .ToList();
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5C%28%28%3F%3D%5C%5B%29%28%3F%3E%5C%28%28%3F%3Cc%3E%29%7C%5B%5E%28%29%5D%2B%7C%5C%29%28%3F%3C-c%3E%29%29*%5C%29%5Cr%3F%24&i=%28%5BtxtData%5D%20of%20COMPOSITE%0D%0A%28dirty%20FALSE%29%0D%0A%28composite%20%5BtxtModel%5D%29%0D%0A%28view%20%5Bstar3%5D%29%0D%0A%28creationIndex%200%29%0D%0A%28creationProps%20%29%0D%0A%28instanceNameSpecified%20FALSE%29%0D%0A%28containsObject%20nil%29%0D%0A%28sName%20txtData%29%0D%0A%28txtDynamic%20FALSE%29%0D%0A%28txtSubComposites%20%29%0D%0A%28txtSubObjects%20%29%0D%0A%28txtSubConnections%20%29%0D%0A%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%28%5BtxtUI%5D%20of%20COMPOSITE%0D%0A%28dirty%20FALSE%29%0D%0A%28composite%20%5BtxtModel%5D%29%0D%0A%28view%20%5Bstar2%5D%29%0D%0A%28creationIndex%200%29%0D%0A%28creationProps%20%29%0D%0A%28instanceNameSpecified%20FALSE%29%0D%0A%28containsObject%20nil%29%0D%0A%28sName%20ApplicationWindow%29%0D%0A%28txtDynamic%20FALSE%29%0D%0A%28txtSubComposites%20%29%0D%0A%28txtSubObjects%20%29%0D%0A%28txtSubConnections%20%29%0D%0A%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%28%5Bstar38%5D%20of%20COMPOSITE%0D%0A%28dirty%20FALSE%29%0D%0A%28composite%20%5BtxtUI%5D%29%0D%0A%28view%20%5Bstar39%5D%29%0D%0A%28creationIndex%2026%29%0D%0A%28creationProps%20composite%20%5BtxtUI%5D%20sName%20Bestellblatt%29%0D%0A%28instanceNameSpecified%20TRUE%29%0D%0A%28containsObject%20COMPOSITE%29%0D%0A%28sName%20Bestellblatt%29%0D%0A%28txtDynamic%20FALSE%29%0D%0A%28txtSubComposites%20%29%0D%0A%28txtSubObjects%20%29%0D%0A%28txtSubConnections%20%29%0D%0A%29&o=m).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?=\[)` - a `[` should immediately follow the current position
- `(?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\)(?<-c>))*` - 0 or more repetitions of

  - `\((?<c>)|` - `(` and an empty value is pushed onto `Group "c" capture stack, or
  - `[^()]+|` - 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`, or
  - `\)(?<-c>)` - `)` and an empty value is popped from `Group "c" capture stack
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `\r?$` - an optional CR and end of a line.